# PHP/Htaccess - problem with a loader

Tags: php, html, include

I have an htaccess file in the root that redirects every request of a page to a specific file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/loader.php(.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$         /loader.php?url=$1    [QSA,L]
```

Now the redirect is easy in the `loader.php`

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . $_GET['url']);
```

I just include the URL,`admin/index.php` for example.

If I leave the code as is the loader will include the file and print the correct HTML, but it will not load any CSS or JS scripts. If I put `echo "test";`
just before the include, the loader will load the CSS file. It's something that is killing me. Do I have to specify something in the HTTP header?

I already tried putting `<base url="" />` in the header of `index.php` with no result, 
but another strange thing is that with Chrom if I inspect the page and click on the link I'll see the right CSS.

---

*Update 1*

I printed the `headers_list();`. I noticed one thing - when I print an `echo` in `headers_list`, an array shows the content-type, so I tried to add it on my own with the `header()` function but with no result. Still working on it.

---

*Update 2*

I've noticed another thing; if I put a `<style></style>` tag with some CSS it will work fine, but if I use the `<link />` tag it doesn't. This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Could you show the output of the page when you include the CSS or JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to send the correct MIME headers for css and javascript (and images etc.).
Easiest is to just let apache handle those requests. Put all the CSS, JS and images in a folder named 'assets' or something and change the htaccess to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/loader.php(.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$         /loader.php?url=$1    [QSA,L]
```

Comment: thanks! it is a very good start... i stil have some problem if the file i open is inside of a folder,i'll create the assets folder there put the css,js,images in, but strangerly only css doesn't work.... any idea? i have to put some rewritecond for every folder inside the root?

Comment: My guess is you have some other problem with you css. Try opening the url of you css in you browser, and see if you get any error.